# Copy and paste in Notepad ++

Tags: file, notepad++, paste

I am compiling 77 individual files into one in Notepad ++. Each is roughly between 31,000 and 33,600 rows apiece. I have researched and found nothing on their being a hard cap on number of rows. I am at item 36 and when I copy its contents in Notepad ++, the pasted result is one long string or single row. Any ideas as to why this would work for the first 35 files and start messing up at 36?

Additional Info: When I paste the 36th text file to the bottom, it puts an E in the top row and then the one long string below that.

Sample. THe third row should be two rows starting with the field 32.

```
32   07  000000   2008
32   07  000001   2008
**32   08  000000   2009  32  08   000001   2009**
```

Comment: "I am compiling 77 individual files into one in Notepad ++" what does that mean?

Comment: Does the first number always be 32? If yes, then you can use regex replace to replace '32' with '\n32'

Comment: I have 77 individual text files that need to be consolidated into one. Every quarter we produce one of these text files but they are independent of each other.

Comment: @HarishTalanki, I am not sure that I understand. I am not finding and replacing but rather taking from one text file to another.

Comment: @TimWilcox you mean *concatenating*?

Comment: @bolov. No, I am trying to copy items from each of the 77 individual files and paste them into one consolidated file.

Comment: It may be that the 36th file has a different lineending convention than the first files. Probably UNIX and the first files have WIndows. Notepad++ shows in the third field from the right of the status bar either `UNIX (LF)` or `Windows (CR LF)`. You can change the convention with Edit -> EOL Conversion -> ... . But consider Jareds answer and automate this task.

Comment: @TimWilcox you mean concatenating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out the command prompt item below. I resolved it, so to speak, by simply putting the 77 text files into 3. Apparently, there is a setting or an issue on my machine that caps it at about 1.49 million rows.

Answer (score 2):

Do this in an automated way!  For example, if you're using windows and have 77 files that end with a `.txt` extension, open a CMD prompt, use`cd` to go to the directory that contains the files, then type the following:

```
type *.txt >> new.txt
```

If you want to run this a 2nd time, first delete the generated file called 'new.txt'.

Comment: OK, trying it now.

Comment: I have a command prompt open and it says "C:\Users\Name> From here do I type in where it is. For example, would it look like this?

    c:\users\name>my documents\file name